# Delete string parts within delimiter

Tags: r, string

I have a string `as"dfgdf" sa"2323"`:

```
a <- "as\"dfgdf\" sa\"2323\""
```

The delimiter (same for the start and the end) here is `"`. So what I want is to get a string were everything is deleted within delimiter but not delimiter itself. So the end result string should look like `as"" sa""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with a regex lookaround to match a word (`\\w+`) that succeeds a double quote and precedes one as pattern and is replaced by blank (`""`)

```
cat(gsub('(?<=")\\w+(?=")', "", a, perl = TRUE), "\n")
#as"" sa""
```

---

Or without regex lookaround

```
cat(gsub('"\\w+"', '""', a), "\n")
#as"" sa""
```

Answer (score 4):

You could match `"` and forget what is matched using `\K`

Then use a negated character class matching any char except `"` or a whitespace character and use lookarounds to assert `"` to the right.

Use `perl=TRUE` to enable Perl-like regular expressions.

```
a <- "as\"dfgdf\" sa\"2323\""
gsub('"\\K[^"\\s]+(?=")', "", a, perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "as\"\" sa\"\""
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/M9VwkF)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another base R option using `paste0` + `strsplit`

```
s <- paste0(paste0(unlist(strsplit(a, '"\\w+"')), '""'), collapse = "")
```

which gives

```
> s
[1] "as\"\" sa\"\""
> cat(s)
as"" sa""
```

Answer (score 2):

I also found a way with stringr library:

```
library(stringr)

a <- "as\"dfgdf\" sa\"2323\""

result <- str_replace_all(a, "\".*?\"", "\"\"")
cat(result)
```